# Highlight the sub text depending on the number of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basic idea is to highlight the characters after a specified length value in input, and also show a notice message.

Here we go:

```
<div id="test_box">
   <input type="text" id="text_text">
</div>
```

css:

```
 #notice {
    width: 140px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;   

    }
 #test_box {
       width: 400px;
       height: 400px;

 }
```

and jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var length = $('#text_text').val().length; 
        var char_limit = 5;       
        $('#text_text').bind('keyup', function() {
            new_length = $('#text_text').val().length;
            if (new_length > char_limit) {
              $('#text_text').css('color','red');
                $('#test_box').append('<div id="notice"> There are limit of character for home page title of this field </div>'); // wrong too much divs :/

            } else {
               $('#text_text').css('color', 'black');
               $('#notice').hide(); //wrong             
            }
        });
 });
```

At the moment characters highlighted after `char_limit` is exceeded, what i need is to highlight only those who go after `char_limit`. And also notice block is adding every time if i input character, i think i should create that div manually or maybe not and appear it somehow when `char_limit` is exceeded.

Comment: Can you just use the `mexlength` property of the textbox? `<input type="text" maxlength="5" value="" id="text_text" />` That will force the issue without a need for the script.

Comment: i cant do that, cuz on my site user can add some content and every content has title, but on the home page i need to show trimmed title and limit is 5 atm, but this is just example(limit will be set later), so i want to allow the user to understand what this title will be trimmed if they promote it on home page.

Comment: if you dont mind using a jquery plugin: [jQuery Caret Plugin](http://www.jquery-plugin.buss.hk/my-plugins/jquery-caret-plugin), is capable of `highlight text by specifying starting position, ending position or length of selection in a "text input box" (input type="text") or "text area" (textarea)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "highlighting" the characters exceeding char_limit. If you want to apply a style to a part of the input text, then it is impossible: styles will apply to the whole input. You can try to simulate an input field with spans and some javascript to listen to the keyboard events. This is explained in [this answer to a similar question as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3121753/39622).

For the notice, indeed, you should not add it every time. it should be in your HTML with css "display:none" and shown and hidden when appropriate.

```
<div id="test_box">
    <input type="text" id="text_text">
    <div id="notice"> There are limit of character for home page title of this field </div>
</div>
```

--

```
#notice {
    width: 140px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;   
    display:none;
}
```

--

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var length = $('#text_text').val().length; 
    var char_limit = 5;       
    $('#text_text').bind('keyup', function() {
        new_length = $('#text_text').val().length;
        if (new_length > char_limit) {
          $('#text_text').css('color','red');
            $('#notice').show();

        } else {
           $('#text_text').css('color', 'black');
           $('#notice').hide();          
        }
    });
```

});

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bu8bK/1/) with that code.

Comment: yes i wanted to apply style to a part of the input, did not know thats impossible as js, about notice thanks for answer! gonna try to simulate that field. thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not really impossible highlight some part of the text as you can highlight it by selection.

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/9BrpD/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var input = $('#text_text');
    var warning = $('#warning');
    input.on('keyup', function(){
       var val = $(this).val();
        if ( val.length > 3 ) {
            warning.html('hello').css('display', 'block');
            l = val.length
            var input = document.getElementById("text_text");
            input.setSelectionRange(l-3, l);
            input.focus();
        }
        else {
             warning.css('display', 'none');
        }
    });   

});​
```

It also solves the issue you had with your repeated divs. However, I don't find this solution very user-friendly. You could try to move the focus outside of the input field but still, not entirely satisfactory.

Comment: about user-friendly u are right, your solution is interesting. thanks for answer