# Is there any way to change one word color of placeholder

Tags: html, css, placeholder

Suppose I have this text field

```
<input type="text" placeholder="I am placeholder">
```

I know with css we can change placeholder color like this but is there any way to change color of one word only.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: pink;
}
```

This code will change complete placeholder color but I want to change color of word `placeholder` only instead on complete `I am placeholder`

Comment: Nope! I don't think something like that exists. You may want to use JS to achieve that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I style individual parts of an input placeholder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655493/how-can-i-style-individual-parts-of-an-input-placeholder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) :

**edit: for nowdays**, see and **use** update below *(3rd snippet)* **with `background-clip`.**

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 2.2em, blue 2.2em);
  border: inset;
  /* border here instead input */
  font-family: monospace;
  /* less surprise about length of text at screen */
}
input {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2em white;
  /* covers the background, needed for the blending */
}
input:invalid {
  /* color part of text only when placeholder is shown */
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
/* snippet disclaimer */

.disclaim {
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
body {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input placeholder="I am placeholder" required />
</label>
<p class="disclaim">not avalaible yet for <span>'your browser',</span> please be patient.</p>
```

Else you need to use HTML and text:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
}
label>span {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
label>span span {
  color: blue
}
input {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
input:invalid {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span>I am <span>placeholder</span></span>
  <input type="text" required />
</label>
```

---

### edit 2020

[`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) is now well supported and can be used instead `mix-blend-mode`

*`mix-blend-mod` trick was a workaround for Firefoxe. Firefoxe understood `color:transparent` but not `background-clip-text;` yet ... text was gone.*

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: monospace;
  /* less surprise about length of text at screen */
}
input:invalid {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 2.2em, blue 2.2em);
  background-clip:text;
  color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input placeholder="I am placeholder" required />
</label>
```

Comment: could you please explain a bit about `mix-blend-mode`

Comment: @GauravAggarwal mix-blend-mode allows different stacking element to mix their colors together through different filters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode . it allows here to blend the dark to blend with gradient colors underneath where white does not . each values have a different effect.

Comment: so can we adjust the size of the color area too?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal yes, here i setted red ont the first 2.2em (i am)  , then the rest will be blue (red/blue can be transparent or any colors)

Answer (score 2):

You can't possibly do it with standard **placeholder**. Instead make a `div` and put your input element and one more child(say `span/p` element) inside this `div` and position `span/p` inside your input element and on focus hide the `span/p` element.

Something like this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22655903/3872578)

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends you should us div tag with an attribute of contenteditable="true" instead of input tag and then find its children elements and change their size color etc using javascript.and I think it is the only answer for your question.And if you only want to change the first letter or word color you should use pseudo selectors.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).