# different text colour for part of string in text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I style part of a string that is the value of a text-input while it is still in the input-field?

I know one can do this with an element with a contentedible attribute in an element, but Google does it in an input of type text with their instant suggestions. The first completion / suggestion appearing in the input.

Comment: can you attach screenshot?

Comment: Google does not use an input for suggestions :) but a `table`. That way they can manipulate styles inside `span` elements.

Comment: @roXon actually, google uses input for search queue and another input under previous one for suggestion.

Comment: @roXon Well, you can manipulate the styles inside a span if its parent is another thing besides a table. It doesn't have to be a table, I don't think.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121683/is-there-a-way-to-style-part-of-an-input-fields-value

Comment: @Klaster_1 Ah, I see. Sounds hacky and involves unnecessary markup. I was just wondering how they did it. Unless, can an input have an open and closed version and have a child then or is it infertile? Meaning, does an input have to look like `<input type="text" />` or can it be `<input type="text">auto<span id="suggestion">complete</span></input>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Google uses something like [this](http://jsbin.com/ozeyiq/2/edit)

Unfortunately you cannot *" open + close "* an `input` element like:

```
<input> <span>Bold</span> normal </input>
```

**My suggestion is to go this way** using `contenteditable`: [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/upowow/2/edit).

```
<div id="input" contenteditable="true"><span>This is </span> quite cool!</div>
```

CSS sample:

```
#input{
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#eee;
  height:20px;
  width:200px;
  padding:7px;
  color:#888;
}
#input span{
  color:#444;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Then in JS to retrieve the element "value" you can use:

```
alert( this.textContent );
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/upowow/3/edit)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of UX, I think the best user experience would to not complete what the user is typing, but to show suggestions / completed options underneath the input.