# How to change the Color of textbox value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having html **input textbox** with value of "Hello World".

I want to change the text color of 'Hello' to red using jquery.

Example:

Textbox Value is Hello World. **Hello** font color is **Red**

Comment: @DaveBriand wish we could make that a pre-requisite before posting on the tags of this question!

Comment: @RobSchmuecker deleted my comment because I don't think there's a jquery course on codecademy :)

Comment: Please post any relevant code snippets that you have tried.

Comment: @DaveBriand way to go ... Ooops! :-)

Comment: I am tried the following code.

var strVale="hai@mail.com,someone@mail.com,example@some.com";
var str = $("#txtGetValue").val();
$("#txtGetValue").val(str.replace(strVale, "<span class='spanError'>" + strVale + "</span>"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't just change **Hello** to `red` and change **world**  to another color. but there is a solution to do this, is to create a `div` and put `spans` inside `div` with different colors, and define click, keyup, keydown events

```
<div class="input">
  <span class="red">Hello</span>
  <span class="green">world !</span>
</div>
```

The question has been [asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121683/is-there-a-way-to-style-part-of-an-input-fields-value#answer-3121753).