# HTML5 in Placeholder jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, placeholder

I want to have a `bold tag` in my `input` `placeholder` like the following:

---

```
|--------------------|
|  BOLD normal       |
|--------------------|
```

I found answers on Google but they're not useful. Like overlaying a `div` over the `input` with `position:relative`.

Is there a way to have HTML in a `placeholder` tag without having to need HTML? Such as a useful jQuery plugin? It doesn't need to be supported on any browsers other than Chrome.

Comment: This isn't possible; you *can* [style placeholder-text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css) but all of the placeholder will have the same style. If you want to have different words/parts of the placeholder styled differently then you will need to use relative-positioning of other elements over the top of the `<input>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to style part of an input field's value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121683/is-there-a-way-to-style-part-of-an-input-fields-value)

Comment: Using css you can set the input font weight to be bold and when the input is focused, set the font weight to normal. No Javascript needed.

Comment: Why do people downvote questions when they don't know the answer ? The question is well formed and the OP has proven he/she has tried something before asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a bold "tag" inside the placeholder. However you can style it in a way to make some of the text bold. You are however limited to either styling the beginning or the end of the text.

```css
input {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 500px;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
  content: " Not so bold here";
  font-weight: normal;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="I'm a pretty bold placeholder text..">
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WryaPM

Comment: Which plateform are you on ? Works for me anyway on a Mac, http://cl.ly/123M1B3u1w3z

Comment: Mmm.. very strange! Not working on Chrome 49 for Win, but yes on Chrome 47 for Android

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This helped a lot!

Comment: @DavidThomas Getting the text value from the attributes looks impossible. It seems that the browser is trying to look for an attribute (data-beforetext) on the placeholder attr.. Did I miss something ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoGzwN

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```css
div.input { border:1px solid #aaa; width:300px; }
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="input"><strong>My name is:</strong> devat karetha</div>
```

Comment: or do like that,`input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}`