# I lose focus of my <input> after i have a regex replacement

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code that is not working:

```js
// money related syntax (yellow)
var SyntaxmoneyReg = /\b(StartingCurrency|Hello)(?=[^\w])/g

function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput")
  var data = input.value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + data;
  data = data.replace(SyntaxmoneyReg, '<span class="code-money">$1</span>');
  input.innerHTML = data;
  document.getElementById("myInput").focus();
}
```

```css
.code-money { color:blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()" contenteditable="true">

  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

After my "data.replace" detects a match, everytime I enter a letter I lose focus of the textbox.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by detects a match, you might want to elaborate? Or give a sample of what is the match? What I do notice is when you erased the textbox back to empty you lose focus of the textbox.

Comment: @Mukyuu what i mean is, when you type "Hello" (one of the words its looking for) and then try to type after that, you keep on losing focus

Comment: Yeah, I've tried typing "Hello" but I'm not losing focus. I lose focus when I erased text from textbox to empty ("")

Comment: @Mukyuu did you put a space in between? try "Hello testing123" and you should lose focus

Comment: Okay, now it show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've moved the `</span>` from the initial data replace. The ***problem*** lies in `$1</span>`.

***Modifying*** into `$i+'</span>'` ***fix the lost focus issue***.

***To activate your span styling*** you need to fix your innerHTML.
The issue lies in `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + data;`. You can ***remove*** the `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + data;` and `input.innerHTML = data;`.

***Adding*** `var div= document.querySelector('div');`

***Then modifying*** `div.innerHTML = "You wrote: " + data;`

***Solve the problem.***

You could also remove `document.getElementById("myInput").focus();` it was redundant.

***Try the following fiddle:***

```js
// money related syntax (yellow)
var SyntaxmoneyReg = /\b(StartingCurrency|Hello)(?=[^\w])/g

function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  var div= document.querySelector('div');
  var data = input.value;
  data = data.replace(SyntaxmoneyReg, '<span class="code-money">$1'+'</span>');
  div.innerHTML = "You wrote: " + data;
}
```

```css
.code-money { color:blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()" contenteditable="true">

  <div id="demo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it seems to wrap **all** the text in the <span>, the point of the <span> is to be able to change the color of the word.

Comment: I don't see the <span> element?

Comment: If you turn on console.log(data); after replacement you would notice "<span class="code-money">Hello</span> testing 123"

Comment: You need to fix your innerHTML. Check the updated fiddle.

Comment: this seems to only style the "you wrote" text, that part was only for testing if the function was firing, it's actually supposed to style the word in the input

Comment: For further information on styling word in the input you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121683/is-there-a-way-to-style-part-of-an-input-fields-value). TL;DR:  styles will apply to the whole input only.