# Styling placeholder text of input field with multiple styles

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to style the placeholder text of a single input field with multiple styles.

I want to style differently the text that is between the span tags in the label (the optional text). The CSS is not working.

```js
$(".label").each(function() {
  el = $(this);
  label_value = el.text();
  el.hide();
  el.next('input').val(label_value).addClass("hide");
});

$("input").focus(function() {
  el = $(this);
  input_value = el.val();
  label_value = el.prev('.label').text();
  if (input_value == label_value) {
    el.val('').removeClass("hide");
  }
})
$("input").blur(function() {
  el = $(this);
  if (el.val() == '') {
    label_value = el.prev('.label').text();
    el.val(label_value).addClass("hide");
  }
});
```

```css
input.hide span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label class="label">Brand <span>(optional)</span></label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="brand" name="brand" value="" />
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `label.hide span{
   color: red
}`

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the title. I did not realize my caps lock was on

Comment: Your question does not seem to match the title. In HTML an input placeholder is a specific attribute with specific properties, but in your question you are only mentioning elements within the label.

Comment: @soupy-norman OP is using a label as a placeholder, yes it's wrong, but it's a common practice

Comment: The selector `input.hide span` makes little sense - and input element can not _have_ any children.

Comment: Plus you got the label element's content using `label_value = el.text();` - so the span is not contained in that value any more to begin with here.

Comment: Instead of setting the value of the input field (which you can't format in multiple different ways to begin with - you have _one_ element to format here, the input field), show the label _behind_ the input field, and give the input a transparent background - then you can apply whatever arbitrary formatting you want to the label contents. (Would still rather be an _abuse_ of a label for that though.)

Answer (score -1):

**el.text()** only return texts of DOM Node. See https://api.jquery.com/text/#text

> Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML
> documents. The result of the .text() method is a string containing the
> combined text of all matched elements. (Due to variations in the HTML
> parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines
> and other white space.) Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="demo-container">
  <div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
  <ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list <strong>item</strong> 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So, label_value is **Brand (optional) label_value**, span tag is ignored.
And, you can't set different color to part of input field. Input has no child at any time. See
[Is there a way to style part of an input field's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121683/is-there-a-way-to-style-part-of-an-input-fields-value)

BTW:Capital title is annoying.

Comment: Please review updated comments - your answer is a little behind (no doubt took a few minutes to formulate)